# Decoding the character table

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-representations, representation-theory, raman-spectroscopy

The following is character table of water molecule
[image]

I would like to know

(1)What does the last 2 column in the table indicate?

(2) How to deduce the functions in the last column?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at page 81 and 82 of [Applications of Group Theory To the Physics of Solids.](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf) by A. Dresselhaus it seems that the second last column are the possible basis functions of that irreducible representation. The last column contains non-basis functions that transform under that irrep.

I think the $A_1$ is the trivial irrep, therefore $z$ is left invariant (basis function) and also the functions $x^2$, $y^2$, $z^2$ are invariant.

Then the $A_2$ is the one which takes care of the $z$-reflection parity. When we reflect through the $xy$-plane, both $x$ and $y$ will incur a sign change and the function $xy$ as well as the angular momentum $R_z$ (spherical harmonic) is invariant.

The $B_1$ and $B_2$ are also one dimensional irreps, they seem to encode the $y$ and $x$ parities. Therefore they leave functions $xy$ and $yz$ invariant, as well as their respective angular momentum. It is just not clear why $x$ is a basis function when $xz$ is conserved, whereas for the $A_2$, $z$ has not been listed as a basis vector.

I suppose you have to read a bit more in those group theory notes in order to find a more precise definition of those two columns.

Comment: what a wonderful book...